# How to make GestureDetector blocked by child in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have found that `GestureDetector` can have different hit test behaviours:

- `deferToChild` to work on non-empty space
- `opaque` and `translucent` to work on all space

But how can I make `GestureDetector` work only on empty space?

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: fallbackHandler, // called only when no children hit
  child: Stack(
    children: manyOtherGestureDetectors, // should keep working, not blocked by the parent
  ),
)
```

One solution could be putting the `GestureDetector` at the bottom layer of a `Stack`:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: fallbackHandler,
    ),
    ...manyOtherGestureDetectors,
  ],
)
```

But it becomes hard to size (shrink) the backgourd `GestureDetector` as it is no longer a parent. One way to shrink it is to use `IntrinsicHeight`, but `IntrinsicHeight` [does not work](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59719) with `TextField`.

So is it possible to create a `GestureDetector` that:

1. Is behind (blocked by) all other `GestureDetector`s;
2. Shrinks its size to exactly wrap all other `GestureDetector`s?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on this, make a try.
You can use the `IgnorePointer` widget to block any gesture for it's child.

Wrap the child with `IgnorePointer` and make `ignoring: true,`

```
Ex: GestureDetector(
  onTap: fallbackHandler, // called only when no children hit
  child: IgnorePointer(
Stack(
    children: manyOtherGestureDetectors, // should keep working, not blocked by the parent
  ),
`ignoring: true,`
),
)
```